# Backbone.js: How can I view all the data attached to a model?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Working in Backbone.js, how can I view in the console all the data available on a model?

By this, I mean a dictionary of everything that is available via:

```
this.model.get("foo");
```

logging something like:

```
{ "foo" : "bar" }
```

I'd like to see all available properties in the console. Just logging `this.model` to the console doesn't show me that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `toJSON()` method which returns a [shallow clone of the model's attributes property](http://documentcloud.github.io/backbone/docs/backbone.html#section-36):

```
toJSON: function(options) {
  return _.clone(this.attributes);
}
```

You can then instantiate your model to view to console on fetch:

```
var model = new FooBar({id: 123});
model.fetch({
  success: function() {
    console.log(model.toJSON());
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it for you:

```
console.log(this.model.toJSON());
```

[toJSON](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-toJSON) will return shallow-copy of a model's attributes. Here is the [annotated source for toJSON](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-35).

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
console.log(this.model.attributes);
```